# markdown problem with single quote (causing highlighting)

Tags: support, markdown

I tried to correct an answer and made it worse: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78199/32191

The author used â instead of ' (in "don't"). As he was quoting a man page he used both ">" for marking as a quote and "        " for making the text formatted as code. Like this:

> ```
>    --skip-old-files
>           don't replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them
> ```

This is evil. The problem does not occur here. Have a look at the linked answer. In the answer the single quote causes unwanted highlighting effects. I cannot get rid of them by prepending a backslash because the backslash is shown then. It seems that the single quote is not considered a special markup character. Should I avoid this problem by using real (Unicode) apostrophe? "don’t"

Answer (score 3):

The "code" is being syntax-highlighted as a bash script because the question has the [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag. You can [override](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) it by putting a comment before the code block:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

But the real solution in this case is to not use code blocks for non-code, particularly within a block quote